# jQuery DOM Traversing .prev()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch an input value with jQuery. In my real code I have more inputs and buttons, so code like: `.middle()`won't work! I need to traverse from the btn and up.

**HTML**

```
<p>Help</p>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" class="findMe" />
<input type="text" />
<button type="submit" class="btn">Alert</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
  //text = $(this).prev('.findMe').val();
  //text = $(this).closest("input").find(".findMe").val();
  alert(text);
})
```

I searched and I did read the docs but I can't get it to work. The alert says "undefined".

The strange thing is, I have other code pretty close to this that works perfectly.

So, what's wrong?

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/6gbm8pgg/

Comment: there is no button which have such class `.btn`?

Comment: @Jai Sorry´deleted to much for this example. The fiddle is correct tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change to this line then:

```
$(this).siblings(".findMe").val();
```

Because your button and other inputs are at same level or i would say they have same parent so they are siblings.

Although there are more ways to do the same like but:
*<sup>(not recommended)</sup>*

```
$(this).parent().find(".findMe").val();
$(this).prevAll(".findMe").val();
$(this).prev().prev(".findMe").val();
```

Comment: Actually! if you go to the documentation you can find in the description that it finds the immediate prev sibling element.

Comment: `Description: Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.` [from the docs](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
$(this).prevAll(".findMe").val();
```

Because **prev()** functions looks only at nearest previous element, **siblings()** looks for all previous and all next elements